# Android onUpgrade gets invoked every time

Tags: android

I am trying to upgrade a certain table by adding a column to a Sqlite table in my android app.I have added an alter table statement in the onUpgrade method of my DBHelper.

Here are the problems that I am seeing
I changed the value of Database version from 1 to 2, so ideally now the onUpgrade should get called.It does get called, but it gets called everytime I instantiate the class.As a result I get a column already exists error.

Here is the onUpgrade method

```
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
    int newVersion) 
    {
        Log.d("old Version",oldVersion+"");
        Log.d("New Version",newVersion+"");
        db.beginTransaction();

        try
        {           
            String DATABASE_UPGRADE;
            DATABASE_UPGRADE="alter table "+DATABASE_TABLE_MESSAGES+" ADD COLUMN  "+ IS_READ+ " integer DEFAULT 0;";
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_UPGRADE);
            Log.d("upgrade", "Successful");
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } 


    finally 
    {
        db.endTransaction();
    }

    }
}
```

I am wondering why the onUpgrade gets called each time!!!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would be willing to bet that the version is not being properly updated on the database (I can't tell why though). To check the version of your database, you can use the `db.getVersion()`.

Comment: There are 2 log.d statements in the onUpgrade method.They show a value of 1 and 2 respectively.So the database version is at 1.I might need to delete the database and try again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor of your database helper are you correctly passing the new version number?

EDIT: should look like this

```
DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
```

and `DATABASE_VERSION` should be 2.

Comment: Thanks Femi for your reply.the DATABASE_VERSION is a public variable which is initialsed at 2.the log.d statements in the onUpgrade show 1 and 2 in the DDMS perspective...

Comment: So the upgrade is probably failing then. Put a `catch` statement before the `finally` and see what happens: you might need to remove the semi-colon at the end of the `alter table` statement and maybe quote the `IS_READ` value.

Comment: Femi is right, your upgrade is probably failing and that's why your version stays at 1. Add a catch and log any exceptions.

Comment: That is correct..When the upgrade happened the first time.. there was no  db.beginTransaction(); or db.setTransactionSuccessful();
 statements.This could be a result why the column was added, but the version did not change.

Comment: There was an additional problem.I have multiple tables in my app, and those have their individual helper classes..those helper classes had the version as 1.

Comment: That would do it. You really should have a single one per database to avoid confusion like that.